# regex problems... making it specific

Tags: regex

regex that say string MUST be of size 9 or 11 characters. It can't have be anything else.I had got it working for 9 or more characters when I did ((\d{9})|(\d{11})$ It is valid when I have 200 characters and that is not what I want...

Comment: 1) fix the typo 2) tell us the regex syntax you're using

Answer (score 2):

You need to anchor the beginning too. Try something like this:

```
^((\d{9})|(\d{11}))$
```

Also, if it can be any 9 or 11 characters, not just digits, use this:

```
^((.{9})|(.{11}))$
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need a start anchor (`^`) or else it will just match 9 or 11 digits at the end of the string:

```
^(\d{9}|\d{11})$
```

Or equivalently:

```
^\d{9}(\d\d)?$
```

And if you just want to match 9 or 11 of any character, use:

```
^.{9}(..)?$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
((\d{9})|(\d{11})$
```

...is not a valid regular expression because it is missing a parenthesis.

Here is the corrected regular expression which you probably intended to write in your question:

```
((\d{9})|(\d{11}))$
```

Now, as to your question, you would like to limit the number of digits entered to only 9 or 11. Here's how to do that:

```
^((\d{9})|(\d{11}))$
```

What we are doing is defining the start `^` and end `$` of the expression so that the regular expression engine knows how to parse the data.

If you don't define a start and an end, the expression is "greedy" by default, which is why it was matching more than 9 or 11 digits. Since you only defined an end, it matched *all* occurrences of start, which is each combination of 9 or 11.

As already pointed out, if you want to match characters, you'll need to substitute a different expression:

```
^((.{9})|(.{11}))$
```

If you only want to match numbers, letters, and underscores, you could use this:

```
^(([A-Za-z_0-9]{9})|([A-Za-z_0-9]{11}))$
```

However, in any case, the expression can be more easily defined as:

```
^.{9,11}$
```

And you would substitute either `[A-Za-z_0-9]` or `\d` depending on your needs.

The additional `()` you have around your original expression are not needed for a basic matching regular expression. They are required if you need capture groups for replacements.